# iPad Multiple Detail Views & Model Tutorial/Example

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ipad

Does anyone know of any sample code or tutorials that implement an iPad split view application that has more than one Detail View in addition to the detail views interacting with a separate model? I ask this because the only examples I have found are of iPad applications that implement multiple detail views but do not interact with any sort of model. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [MultipleDetailViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html) Sample code ?